# How do I determine where my YouTube video has been embedded?

Tags: youtube

Using YouTube Analytics, I have been able to determine that one of our competitors is embedding our videos, apparently passing them off as their own (as recently as Sunday).

I have been trying to discover what specific page the videos are embedded on, not just the domain. Apparently this was a capability of Insight, but I haven't been able to find any recent info that shows how to do this using YT Analytics. I suspect this data in no longer available.

I've been all over their site, and tried some obvious unlinked page guesses (/videos, /youtube, etc) and haven't found them.

Is there a way with the current YouTube system to find the specific URL where my videos are embedded?

Comment: Slightly off-topic for your question, but your competitor can only do this if you don't brand your videos. Wouldn't it be safer to include some branding in your video - then there's no doubt where the clip came from.

Comment: They are branded, but according to the stats it looks like they've only showed them to people from Chile, Japan and Columbia (where neither of our companies have much traction), so the viewer may not know the difference. Or perhaps they are using them to contrast our systems, but then it seems weird they would go to the trouble of embedding them. Thanks for the suggestion, it's good advice.